# Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Property ‘X’ in class ‘Y’ is nullable on one side and not on the other

Tags: mongodb, realm

I get below message for ‘rate’. in both Booking class and schema, it is not a ‘required’ item. but i still get this error. pls help.

why is it so difficult for mongodb to tell in which side it is nullable?

Failed to transform received changeset: Schema mismatch: Property ‘rate’ in class ‘Booking’ is nullable on one side and not on the other.

below is my Booking class variables.

```
@PrimaryKey
private ObjectId _id = new ObjectId();
private String name = “Task”;
private String mobile = “”;
private String templocktime;

@Required
private String user_id = "My Project";
@Required
private String date = "30051986";
@Required
private String starttime = "0000";
@Required
private String duration = "60";
@Required
private String status = BookingStatus.Available.name();
private long bookingTime;
private int rate;
```

below is my schema.

```
{
    "title": "Booking",
    "bsonType": "object",
    "properties": {
        "_id": {
            "bsonType": "objectId"
        },
        "user_id": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "date": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "starttime": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "duration": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "status": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "name": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "mobile": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "templocktime": {
            "bsonType": "string"
        },
        "bookingTime": {
            "bsonType": "long"
        },
        "rate": {
            "bsonType": "int"
        }
    },
    "required": ["user_id", "date", "starttime", "duration", "status"]
}
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear. The properties on the server must match the client. e.g. if it's nullable "on one side" it has the nullable on the other. So the server doesn't need to tell a difference between the two, as they should be the same. From the docs *Primitive types such as int and the RealmList type are implicitly required* e.g. they can be nullable but you must specify that.

Comment: I didnt know that Primitive types are implicitly required.  by adding required tag to 'rate' solved my issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the property types on the server will match the client - if it's optional on the server, it will be optional on the client.

There are some properties that by default are implicitly required, such as int's and RealmList. Adding the required tag will ensure it's required in your schema.

See [Optionality](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/fundamentals/object-models-and-schemas/#optionality)

From the docs

You can make any of the following types required:

```
String
UUID
ObjectId
Integer
Long
Short
Byte or byte[]
Boolean
Float
Double
Date
RealmList
```

> Primitive types such as int and the RealmList type are implicitly
> required. Fields with the RealmObject type are always nullable, and
> cannot be made required.